# C# DispatcherTimer in DLL application never triggered

Tags: c#, dispatchertimer

I want to use C# Timer in DLL application

```
DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = interval;
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

but the problem is that is never triggered. Method `dispatcherTimer_Tick` is never triggered even if time is 5 minutes. There is no error nothing.

Any idea why? I am using .net 4.0

Comment: What do you mean by "DLL application"? A DLL doesn't run by itself, it can only be used by an executable. What kind of executable is it? Is it an app with a UI?

Comment: This code will only work if it runs on the *main thread* of a WPF or Store app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `System.Timers.Timer` instead,

```
    System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5 * 60 * 1000);            
    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Elapsed);            
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
    myTimer.Start();
```

This works in all the application type, whether app is web, console, WPF etc  and you do not need to worry about the environment or application it is been used.

Answer (score 1):

For `DispatcherTimer` to work, your app must be running a message pump. If it's a console application or web application, there isn't a message pump, so `DispatcherTimer` can't work.

`DispatcherTimer` is designed for use in WPF applications. If you need a timer in an application with no UI, use `System.Threading.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer`.